# CloubBlockBlob AcquireLease gives two lease to two worker role

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I am developping an application and I have an error from time to time, I have to synchronize several worker roles with a lease on a blob.

Below is my init code for worker role

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("StorageAccount"));
string blobContainerName = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("BlobContainer");
CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
string blobName = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("BlobToBeLeased");
_blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

if (!_blob.Exists())
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is dummy data")))
    {
        try
        {
            _blob.UploadFromStream(ms);
        }
        catch (StorageException storageException)
        {
            if (storageException.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode != 412)
                throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my AcquireLease method:

```
private void AcquireLease()
{
    try
    {
        var leaseId = _blob.AcquireLease(null, null);
        Trace.WriteLine("==========> Lease acquired! <========== ID => " + leaseId);
        _accessCondition = new AccessCondition {LeaseId = leaseId};
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("==========> Lease rejected! <==========");
    }
}
```

A screenshot of the problem:
[image]

The problem is when I call the AcquireLease method it sometimes gives me two leases... Anyone has an idea on how to solve this...

Are CloudBlockBlob operations atomic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a talk with a guy from Microsoft it appears that the emulator does have some discrepencies from the storage service itself.

Running the same code on Azure works fine!

This answer is valid for emulator v1.8.0.0.